# Used Dir.glob to gather files from a directory, now I want to move them all into a folder. How?

Tags: file, move, glob

```
docx_files = Dir.glob("/Users/jorgeolivero/desktop/*.docx")     # Grabbed all of the .docx files on my desktop.
```

Now I would like to move them into a folder on desktop named 'target_folder', how can I do this?

I tried this, but it returned 'undefined local variable or method `fileutils' for main:Object (NameError)'

```
    require 'fileutils'

    docx_files.each do |x|
      fileutils.mv Dir( 'x', '/Users/desktop/jorgeolivero/target_folder' )
    end
```

This is the beginning of my 3rd week learning Ruby and it is my 1st project. I apologize if this question seems elementary. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require 'fileutils'

docx_files.each do |x|
    FileUtils.mv x, "/Users/desktop/jorgeolivero/target_folder"
end
```